# KML Zoom проблема

Tags: google-maps-api

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает зум в данном коде? Я бы хотел, что бы зум карты определялся из KML файла

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: {lat: 48.25450093195546, lng: -90.86948943473118}
    });

    var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://blahblah.ru/map/get-points'
    });
    georssLayer.setMap(map);
```

xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1"><Placemark><name>Простая метка</name><description>Привязана к земной поверхности. Приспосабливается к рельефу местности.</description><Point><coordinates>-90.86948943473118,48.25450093195546,1</coordinates></Point></Placemark></kml>`

У меня в итоге получается зум с максимальным приближением...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как он должен работать? Оставаться равным 5 после загрузки kml? Вот здесь [Google Maps zoom gets overriden, when using a kml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187837/google-maps-zoom-gets-overriden-when-using-a-kml-file), по-моему, похожая проблема и мысли/cоветы доброго человека по этому поводу.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!